# NServiceBus Distributor/Worker ConfigurationErrorsException - 'MasterNodeConfig.Node' points to a local host name: [localhost]

Tags: nservicebus

I am attempting to configure a NServiceBus Distributor/Worker for development purposes. I have the following dependencies installed:

- NServiceBus.Core v5.2.14
- NServiceBus.Distributor.MSMQ  v5.0.4
- NServiceBus.Host v6.0.0

A ConfigurationErrorsException is thrown in one of the workers with the following message:

> 'MasterNodeConfig.Node' points to a local host name: [localhost]

The intent of this error is clear. A configuration pointing to localhost defeats the purpose of the distributed architecture. Although for development purposes this type of configuration is optimal. Below is the configuration of my worker:

```
<TransportConfig MaxRetries="5"/>

<MasterNodeConfig Node="localhost"/>
<UnicastBusConfig
  DistributorControlAddress="distributor.distributor.control@localhost"
  DistributorDataAddress="distributor@localhost">
    <MessageEndpointMappings></MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>

<MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error"/>
```

In the link below is a working sample :

[Scale Out with the Distributor](http://docs.particular.net/samples/scaleout/distributor/)

Comparing my solution to the example in the link above it is unclear what may be causing the ConfigurationErrorsException in my worker. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to create a sample for the Distributor that can run on a single machine, which by definition is supposed to run on multiple machines, is somewhat difficult. (The sample does discuss scaling out in a real environment further down. We added a note near the top to link to it.)

The part in the sample that isn't in your code is an appSetting:

```
<appSettings>
  <add 
    key="NServiceBus/Distributor/WorkerNameToUseWhileTesting" 
    value="Samples.Scaleout.Worker1" />
</appSettings>
```

If this setting is present, the check for loopback addresses in the MasterNode config will be skipped. This is, unfortunately, not documented, and may exist only to make this sample work. We will investigate and resolve as part of the issue I raised.

In real life, however, you should really use full machine names rather than localhost. That, of course, you can't do in a sample.

Another item is that the `MasterNodeConfig` and the `DistributorControlAddress`/`DistributorDataAddress` attributes on `UnicastBusConfig` don't really go together, or don't need to.

`MasterNodeConfig` is meant to be a simple way to configure all endpoints with the very same configuration file. If the endpoint is `Sales` and the MasterNode is `ServerA`, then the control address is `Sales.Control@ServerA` and the data address is `Sales@ServerA`. But that always assumes multiple machines. So the two attributes allow you to specify custom queues that may be on the same machine. Therefore, if you're using the two attributes, you really shouldn't be using `MasterNodeConfig` at all.

Comment: That was the missing piece.  Thank you David.

Comment: @Pietro depending on what your release timeline is, beta NSB 6 may be a good option for you. Particular removed the need for the distributor for scaling the MSMQ transport. There are loads other benefits that make NSB 6 a good choice. However, particular hasn't said when they plan to release v6, but several Particular devs I know are optimistic for an EOY release. David, you want to drop something more concrete ;) ?